# Upload data to Google Sheets using C# .NET API v4 from ADO DataReader

Tags: c#, ado, google-sheets-api

Using the Google Sheets API Version v4 for .NET in C# how do the values get assigned to the ValueRange from an ADO DataReader.

The online documentation from Google typically has code that looks like this:

```
// TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`. All existing
// properties will be replaced:
Data.ValueRange requestBody = new Data.ValueRange();
```

Clearly this is where the data values should be set.  In testing, it is possible to do the following successfully:

```
string range = "MySheet!A2:B";
var MyDataList = new List<object>() { "My Cell Text", "More text" };
RequestBody.Values = new List<IList<object>> { MyDataList };
```

Previous attempts to solve this issue involved creating a class to match the data from the reader and making a List of the objects. Then a line of code like the following was used:

```
RequestBody.Values = new List<IList<object>> { new List<object>(MyDataAsList) } ;
```

This returns the following error:

> Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled
>    HResult=-2146233088
>    Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Invalid values[1][0]:

I'm open to suggestions on other solutions to get the content of a SQL query to output to a Google Sheet.

TIA,
Joshua